# Integer equation with one parameter

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to find positive integers $f = f(n)$ and $g = g(n)$ both dependent on $n \in \mathbb N$ so that

$$ \frac1g + \frac1f = \frac{3}{3n-2} $$

for all $n$ (Or at least all $n>N$ where $N$ is a arbitrary bound.)

I have no clue how to even begin to tackle this problem.  The only thing up to now is $\displaystyle\frac1g + \frac1f = \frac{f+g}{fg}$ which is pretty trivial.

Comment: can you solve for k=3? Would be useful to see what it looks like

Comment: You haven't told us what you mean by $k$.

Comment: I suppose he means $n$ instead of k.

Comment: Of course I mean $n$ thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even ($n=2q$), then $f(2q)=3q-1$ and $g(2q)=2(3q-1)$ are working.

If $n$ is odd ($n=2q+1$) and the problem is equivalent to $\frac{1}{f}+\frac{1}{g}=\frac{3}{6q+1}$.

Wolfram was not able to find a solution for all the random $q$ I tried so I am not sure there is a solution, even for large $n$.

But maybe @user159870 method will be able to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $n$ instead of $k$:

Edit:

$$\frac{1}{f}+\frac{1}{g}=\frac{3}{3n-2} \Rightarrow (3n-2)(g+f)=3fg $$

$$3 \mid (3n-2)(g+f) \Rightarrow 3 \mid 3n-2 \text{ or } 3 \mid g+f$$

$$3 \mid 3n \text{ if } \Rightarrow 3 \mid 3n-2 \text{ then } 3 \mid 3n-(3n-2) \Rightarrow 3 \mid 2 $$

So $$3 \mid f+g \Rightarrow f+g=3m \Rightarrow f=3m-g$$

Replace this in $(3n-2)(g+f)=3fg$

$$(3n-2)(g+3m-g)=3(3m-g)g \Rightarrow (3n-2)3m=9mg-3g^2 \Rightarrow \\ 3g^2-9mg+(3n-2)3m=0$$

SOlve for $g$ using the discriminant.

Then replace this at $f=3m-g$ to find $f$.

Comment: Can you give an argument why $f$ is an integer in this case? (And it requires $3g > 3n-2$)

Comment: Look at my edited answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, that looks more promising! I like the contradiction part=)  So here we have to assume that $m$ depends on $n$ too, right?

Comment: $m$ does not necessarily depend on $n$. We only know that $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. When you find the solutions for $g$ from the discriminant, $g$ will depend on $n$. Then since $f=3m-g$, depends on $g$, $f$ will also depends on $n$.

Comment: So the discriminant of the quadratic equation in g is $D_g = 81m^2-36(3n-2)m$. $D_g \geq 0$ if $m \in \mathbb Z \setminus \left] \frac{1 - 6^2(3n-2)}{2\cdot 6^2}, \frac{1 +6^2(3n-2)}{2\cdot 6^2} \right[$ since for $D_g = 0$ is $m = \frac{1 \pm 6^2(3n-2)}{2\cdot 6^2}$ So $m$ depends on $n$?

Comment: $$D_g=0 \Rightarrow m=0 \text{ or } m=\frac{4}{9}(3n-2)$$
$$D_g \geq 0 \text{ if } m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \left (0, \frac{4}{9}(3n-2) \right ) \text{ if } n>\frac{2}{3}$$ So for different $n$, the interval on which $m$ is, changes.

Answer (score 0):

if $n = 3$ you get a target sum of $3/7$ and clearly there is no solution of the form $1/f + 1/g$ where $f$ and $g$ are positive integers. In general, any time $p = 3n - 2$ is prime there shouldn't be any solutions to get a target sum of $3/p$.

Comment: How did you conclude that there are no solutions for when $3n-2$ is prime?

Comment: Since the target sum is $3/p$, either $f$ or $g$ must be less than $p$ and hence not divisible by $p$. If both $f$ and $g$ are less than $p$ then the sum has a denominator that is not divisible by $p$ in lowest terms. If $f = p$ then clearly there is no solution because we would need $1/g = 2/p$. If $f = kp$ for $k > 1$ then $g < p$ and we get $(kp+g)/kpg$ and we need $kp + g$ to be divisible by $kg$ but this is also impossible.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation;  $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{3}{3q-2}$$

Degradable number of multipliers.  $$(k-3t)(k+3t)=4(3q-2)^2$$

Find.  $k,t$ Substitute in the formula and solutions are.

$$a=q+\frac{\pm{k}-4-3t}{6}$$

$$b=q+\frac{\pm{k}-4+3t}{6}$$

What's difficult could that be?

Let  $q=4$ Then:  $3q-2=10$

$$(k-3t)(k+3t)=4*10^2=10*40$$

$$k=3t+10$$

$$6t=40-10$$

$$t=5$$

$$k=25$$

$$a=4+\frac{25-4-15}{6}=5$$

$$b=4+\frac{25-4+15}{6}=10$$

$$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{3}{10}$$

Comment: I was not able to follow. What do you mean by 'degradable number of multipliers'? Where do those equations come from (I cannot even how you got the first one.) So $k$ and $t$ are constants here?